# Attaching JavaSE EntityManager to JTA

Tags: java, cdi, entitymanager, jta, jpa-2.1

I'm working with JBoss Wildfly as an application server on my JPA layer.

For technical requirements i need to get my entity persistence manager using the JavaSE/application managed approach. I. e.:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("idelivery", properties); 
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
MyEntity exUser= new MyEntity();
try{
    Context context = new InitialContext();
    UserTransaction userTransaction = (UserTransaction)context.lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
    userTransaction.begin();
    em.persist(exUser);
    userTransaction.commit();
```

where in properties i set:

```
properties.put ("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.provider", "org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"); 
    properties.put("javax.persistence.transactionType", "JTA");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jtaDataSource", dataSourcePath);
```

The problem, of course, is with the code lines above I cannot bind the entitymanager to the container JTA transaction manager.

So my question is: is there some example or some way I can make the entity manager to join a complicated JTA transaction? I don't know... maybe with a CDI producer the way i can put the entitymanager inside the container context?

Answer (score 0):

In Java EE environment, you may inject EntityManagerFactory and use it to create EntityManager with custom properties. Therefore, instead of

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("idelivery", properties); 
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

you should do something like:

```
// inject emf from container
@PersistenceUnit("idelivery")
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

// and in your method create em with your properties...
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(properties);
```

Comment: thanks...but this way i cross over my dynamicity requirements. I need to initialize EntityManagerFactory with the SE createEntityManagerFactory because i have to set datasource at runtime and to change it dynamically.

Comment: Passing properties into `emf.createEntityManager(properties)` is not dynamic enough? Or the problem is that it ignores properties that modify datasource?

Comment: oh... sorry... i missed that (properties) ... surely i have to try... let you know...!!! thanks

Comment: well, i'm using Jersy and HK2... @PersistenceUnit( unitName= "KAS-Mapping-AppHandled") doesn't inject anything... do you know how i can lookup for the EntityManagerFactory?

Comment: Well, in case you are not using Java EE features, you need to use your app server specific configuration. For Wildfly, try [this recipe](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-BindingEntityManagerFactory%2FEntityManagertoJNDI)

Comment: i'm able to get the entity manager factory thanks to your suggestion. But now, when i attach it to the usertransaction (i got it byt ut = (UserTransaction)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");) i get a TABLE NOT FOUND exception after the commit. The trick is the exception is from the h2 driver.... but i set my datasource to work with oracle jdbc

Comment: This doesn't occur if i specify the datasource inside the persistence.xml, but i cannot do this as it's a mandatory requirements. Datasource have to be attached at runtime.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm out of ideas so far